# Score board from database with tkinter and SQLite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I've been adding a little extra functionality to a sample snake game which I downloaded from git hub but have hit a bit of a brick wall with regard to the score board. At the moment the extras I've added are:

- A username entry and validation at the start of the game
- Username displayed as the game is playing
- Username and score are written to a database at the end of the game
- A leaderboard is displayed at the end of the game

At the moment my leaderboard only pulls the data from the database and displays it in a label. Ideally I want it to read all of the data into some kind of data structure and only display the top 15 scores after a sort is performed on the records. Is there a relatively simple way to achieve this at all?

Here is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import messagebox, END
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

MOVE_INCREMENT = 20
MOVES_PER_SECOND = 15
GAME_SPEED = 1000 // MOVES_PER_SECOND

class Snake(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, parent, username):
        self.username = username
        super().__init__(
            parent, width=600, height=620, background="black", highlightthickness=0
        )

        # Rest of the Snake class code goes here
        self.snake_positions = [(100, 100), (80, 100), (60, 100)]
        self.food_position = self.set_new_food_position()
        self.direction = "Right"

        self.score = 0
        self.load_assets()
        self.create_objects()

        self.bind_all("<Key>", self.on_key_press)

        self.pack()

        self.after(GAME_SPEED, self.perform_actions)

    def load_assets(self):
        try:
            self.snake_body_image = Image.open("./assets/snake.png")
            self.snake_body = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.snake_body_image)

            self.food_image = Image.open("./assets/food.png")
            self.food = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.food_image)
        except IOError as error:
            print(error)
            root.destroy()

    def create_objects(self):

        self.create_text(45, 12, text=f"Score: {self.score}", tag="score", fill="#fff", font=(10))
        self.create_text(490, 12, text=f"Username: {self.username}", tag="username", fill="#fff", font=(10))
        for x_position, y_position in self.snake_positions:
            self.create_image(
                x_position, y_position, image=self.snake_body, tag="snake"
            )

        self.create_image(*self.food_position, image=self.food, tag="food")
        self.create_rectangle(7, 27, 593, 613, outline="#525d69")

    def check_collisions(self):
        head_x_position, head_y_position = self.snake_positions[0]

        return (
                head_x_position in (0, 600)
                or head_y_position in (20, 620)
                or (head_x_position, head_y_position) in self.snake_positions[1:]
        )

    def check_food_collision(self):
        if self.snake_positions[0] == self.food_position:
            self.score += 1
            self.snake_positions.append(self.snake_positions[-1])

            self.create_image(
                *self.snake_positions[-1], image=self.snake_body, tag="snake"
            )

            self.food_position = self.set_new_food_position()
            self.coords(self.find_withtag("food"), *self.food_position)

            score = self.find_withtag("score")
            self.itemconfigure(score, text=f"Score: {self.score}", tag="score")

    def end_game(self):
        self.delete(tk.ALL)
        self.create_text(
            self.winfo_width() / 2,
            self.winfo_height() / 2,
            text=f"Game over! You scored {self.score}!",
            fill="#fff",
            font=("", 8)
        )

    def write_to_database(self):
        try:
            # Open the Score Database
            connection = sqlite3.connect("ScoreDatabase.db")
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            UserRec = []
            UserRec.append(self.username)
            UserRec.append(self.score)

            # SQL statement to insert the user record into the Gamers table
            buffer = "INSERT INTO Gamers VALUES (?, ?)"
            cursor.execute(buffer, (self.username, self.score))
            connection.commit()
            connection.close()


        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])
            connection.close()

        # End of new database code

    def show_database_entries(self):
        try:
            con = sqlite3.connect("ScoreDatabase.db")
            cur = con.cursor()
            # Show all rows in the database
            buffer = "SELECT * FROM Gamers;"
            buffer = buffer.strip()
            cur.execute(buffer)
            rows = cur.fetchall()
            count = 0
            print()
            print("Database entries  -Username   Score")
            for x in rows:
                print(str(x[0]) + ": " + str(x[1]))
                count += 1
            print()

            con.commit()
            con.close()

        except sqlite3.Error as e:
            print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])
            connection.close()

    def move_snake(self):
        head_x_position, head_y_position = self.snake_positions[0]

        if self.direction == "Left":
            new_head_position = (head_x_position - MOVE_INCREMENT, head_y_position)
        elif self.direction == "Right":
            new_head_position = (head_x_position + MOVE_INCREMENT, head_y_position)
        elif self.direction == "Down":
            new_head_position = (head_x_position, head_y_position + MOVE_INCREMENT)
        elif self.direction == "Up":
            new_head_position = (head_x_position, head_y_position - MOVE_INCREMENT)

        self.snake_positions = [new_head_position] + self.snake_positions[:-1]

        for segment, position in zip(self.find_withtag("snake"), self.snake_positions):
            self.coords(segment, position)

    def on_key_press(self, e):
        new_direction = e.keysym

        all_directions = ("Up", "Down", "Left", "Right")
        opposites = ({"Up", "Down"}, {"Left", "Right"})

        if (
                new_direction in all_directions
                and {new_direction, self.direction} not in opposites
        ):
            self.direction = new_direction

    def perform_actions(self):
        if self.check_collisions():
            self.end_game()
            self.write_to_database()
            show_leaderboard()


        self.check_food_collision()
        self.move_snake()

        self.after(GAME_SPEED, self.perform_actions)

    def set_new_food_position(self):
        while True:
            x_position = randint(1, 29) * MOVE_INCREMENT
            y_position = randint(3, 30) * MOVE_INCREMENT
            food_position = (x_position, y_position)

            if food_position not in self.snake_positions:
                return food_position

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Snake")
root.withdraw() # Hide root window for now

def StartGame():

    username = UsernInput.get()
    if len(username) > 8:
        messagebox.showwarning("Invalid username", "Please enter a username of 8 characters or less")
        window.focus()
    else:
        window.destroy() # Get rid of the username input
        root.deiconify() # Show the root window again
        root.tk.call("tk", "scaling", 4.0)
        root.resizable(False, False)
        board = Snake(root, username)


    return username

def show_leaderboard():
    leaderboard = tk.Toplevel()
    leaderboard.focus
    leaderboard.title("Leaderboard")
    leaderboard.geometry('400x500')
    leaderboard['bg'] = 'black'
    leaderboard.tk.call("tk", "scaling", 4.0)
    leaderboard.resizable(False, False)

    Usern_label = tk.Label(leaderboard, text="High Scores", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
    Usern_label.place(x=10, y=15)
    Usern_label.config(fg="yellow")
    Usern_label.config(bg="black")

    my_con = sqlite3.connect('ScoreDatabase.db')
    cursor = my_con.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SELECT *, oid FROM Gamers LIMIT 15")
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    showData = ''
    for data in data:
        showData = showData.replace("'", "")
        showData = showData.replace(",", "")
        showData = showData.replace("(", "")
        showData = showData.replace(")", "")
        showData += str(data) + "\n"

    results = tk.Label(leaderboard, text=showData, justify='left', width=15, font=("Arial", 6))
    results.place(x=0, y=85)
    results.config(fg="white")
    results.config(bg="black")

    my_con.commit()
    my_con.close()
# New database code

#Create or open the Score Database * This works fine
connection = sqlite3.connect("ScoreDatabase.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

# SQL statement to create the table structure of the Scoredatabase
try:
    # following code runs once to create a new database named above
    buffer ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Gamers (Username, Score, primary key(Username));"
    buffer = buffer.strip()
    cursor.execute(buffer)
    connection.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as e:
    print("An error occurred:", e.args[0])
    connection.close()

# End of new database code

window = tk.Toplevel()
window.title("Snake game")
window.geometry('300x175')
window['bg']='black'

Instructions_label = tk.Label(window, bg='black', text="Enter your username to be entered into the score database. Usernames must be 8 characters or less ", wraplength=300, justify='left', font=("Arial Bold", 12))
Instructions_label.place(x=10, y=10)
Instructions_label.config(fg="#FFFFFF")
Instructions_label.config(bg="black")

Usern_label= tk.Label(window, bg='black', text="Username: ", font=("Arial Bold", 12))
Usern_label.place(x=10, y=90)
Usern_label.config(fg="#FFFFFF")
Usern_label.config(bg="black")

UsernInput = tk.Entry(window, bg='White', bd=1, width=20, highlightthickness=2)
UsernInput.place(x=110, y=90)
UsernInput.config(highlightbackground = "yellow", highlightcolor= "yellow")
usern_button = tk.Button(window, text='Start Game', bd='3', command=StartGame)
usern_button.place(x=20, y=130)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL: `SELECT *, oid FROM Gamers ORDER BY Score DESC LIMIT 15`.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer with regard to the fact I want the Python program itself to sort the data rather than sort it with a SQL statement.

Comment: If you do not sort in SQL, you may not get the 15 records with highest scores.  You need to remove `LIMIT 15` from the SQL to retrieve all records instead.

Comment: @Razorbill Why do you want python to do the sorting when SQL could do it with a very simple change to the query?

Comment: The course I'm working my way through involves using sorts and searches in Python, I am reasonably confident I can program such a thing in Python but am less sure how to read the data into the program from the database in such a way that makes that possible. I know that the LIMIT 15 part will need to go, I had added it in to see what the leader board would look like.

Comment: From what you said in the comment, the result of `fetchall()` (2D array) is what you need to save.  Then you can *sort* and *search* on this 2D array.